# Using Groovy 3 YamlBuilder with Yaml that contains a hyphen

Tags: groovy, yaml

I'm trying to write a Groovy 3 script that uses yamlbuilder to write a yaml file. I have it working on almost everything apart from;

```
execution:
  set-props:
    url:http://myhouse.net
    port:8000
```

How do I write a map that allows the use of a hyphen in the name? Following my previous work I foolishly tried;

```
def setprops=[:]
setprops=(["url":"http://myhouse.net","port":"8000"])
execution.set-props=setprops
```

Which gives me an error 'The LHS of an assignment should be a variable or a field'.

If I just use execution.setprops then it works fine, but of course the resulting yaml from yaml(execution) is invalid.

I think if the set-props was a a key/value pair then it could go into quote and everything would be good. But because it is part of the structure I don't know what needs to be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use strings as "methods" and the builder will create your
intermediate structures from them:

```
import groovy.yaml.YamlBuilder

def b = new YamlBuilder()

b.execution {
    "set-props"(
        url: "..."
    )
}

println b
```

Or to continue on your example: You can create the whole map and use is as argument, where you want to have that content.

```
def setprops=["set-props": [url:"..."]]
b.execution(setprops)
```

Both result in:

```yaml
---
execution:
  set-props:
    url: "..."
```

Note that the first version nests via passed closures and then passes in the map.  The second bit just passes a nested map.

Comment: Ah, so this changes my approach much earlier in the code. For me I was defining a Groovy map, with the relevant maps/lists inside it depending on what the yaml required. But you're starting with a yamlbuilder rather than a map, then passing maps into it. I will try the same with starting with a yamlbuilder, but how would your solution change if b was a map rather than a yamlbuilder?